# How can I get five quick actions in Action Center?

Tags: 8.1, action-center

I'm running Windows Phone 8.1 on a Nokia Lumia 920, and can have four quick actions in Action Center.

However, I've seen pictures online that show Action Center with five quick actions. For example:

[image]

How can I have this on my phone? Is there a setting I need to enable (like the "Show more Tiles" option that adds an extra column of tiles on the Start screen)? Or is it tied to some hardware capabilities like screen resolution or size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only [large screen phones](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-US/OEM/docs/Customization/Customizations_for_Settings) get 5 actions:

> Users can choose which 4 (or 5 for large screen phones).... If an OEM sets the > value for Slot 5, but the phone is not a large screen device, the setting for Slot 5 is ignored.

Unfortunately that page doesn't state what a large screen device actually is.

Answer (score 0):

5 quick action button is only available for Nokia Lumia 1520. Currently, phones except Lumia 1520 have only 4 Quick Action buttons. But we can expect more Action buttons in future as in Android and iOS.

Yes you can check [this article](http://m.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-81-blazes-lumia-1520-video-tour) from wpcentral

You can put your [suggestions here!](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/status/401050)

Comment: Do you have any source to confirm that only the 1520 gets five quick actions? What about other FullHD phones like the 930 or the new Samsung ATIV SE? Or phablets like the 1320?

Comment: Please see updated answer

Comment: The article you linked to says that having five quick actions is dependent on resolution. That contradicts your claim that it's only available for the 1520 because there are other Windows Phone handsets with FHD screens.

Comment: Currently it is available for Nokia Lumia 1520. I did mentioned that currently you will not find 5 action buttons except Lumia 1520.