# Add quick actions trought editing file system

Tags: 8.1

How can I add more quick actions on my Windows Phone 8.1 Lumia Denim? Quick actions are:

[image: Quick actions]

I have full access to file system of my phone (Lumia 820) from pc so I can edit files. Does anyone know which file/s contains information about quick actions and, therefore, which one I can edit?

I've seen [this question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3727/how-can-i-get-five-quick-actions-in-action-center), but it isn't what I want. Lumia 820 has 4.3" (small screen) so can't normally have 5 quick actions.

---

**Update**:

I've found that in: `HKML\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Settings\QuickSettingElements\Pinned`, key `AllowedQuickSettingsElements` I can set the number of quick actions but value *4* is always re-setted.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the actual answer offhand, but the quick actions are almost certainly stored in the registry, not in the file system (per se; registry hives are file but they are locked while the phone is running). If you have full FS access, though, you also have registry access. Depending on how the quick actions are implemented, though, you may not be able to meaningfully edit them.

Comment: What do you mean by "full access"? Do you have access to the registry files?

Comment: @RareNCool Thanks to Interop-unlock I can go on every folder and file of my phone, not just pictures and document. I can have access to the registers too, that are in special path (if it is like Windows).